# DEL key not working

Tags: laptop

I am new to Ubuntu and have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Until the day before yesterday, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key was working, but suddenly it has stopped working.

I have tried to restart the PC, but it didn't work. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes permanently.

Can anybody please guide me how can I get the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key working again.

Comment: What do you by "does not work"? Are you trying to say that it doesn't work _anywhere_ you use it (e.g., a text edit) or just that it does not delete folders in Nautilus (the file manager)?

Comment: I am sorry as I should have given more detailed report. It works in text edit mode but not in file explorer (specially in HDD). When I select an item in my pen drive explorer window and press 'DEL' it goes to recycle bin. But for HDD file window, pressing 'DEL' does not work. Pressing 'Shift'+'DEL' deletes the file permanently. Please help me on this.

Comment: @user282225 Can you delete files on your HDD from the context menu? (right click → *Move to trash*)

Comment: yes, I can delete files using context menu, but I want to do it using DEL key. Earlier I could move files to Trash using DEL, but now I can't do so. What's more funny is that, I can delete files from an USB drive using simply the DEL key. I have installed gonf-editor and dconf-editor and enabled the use of Accelerator but nothing happens. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Therefore I am tempted to say: This is this a bug.